# Returning a variable from a filter. Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to set up some basic routing logic. I have a route that will process a certain URL pattern. These URLs will usually be an ajax request (returning data for a popup window). However, search engines and users with javascript disabled will follow a normal link, so I want the data to be returned on a separate page. To do this, I need to determine if the request is ajax. I understand I can do this using:

```
if(Request::ajax()){
   //
}
```

My plan was to do this as part of a 'before' filter attached to the route. If my thinking is correct, I would need to return a boolean ajax=true/false back from the filter. Maybe this is a very simple question, but I can't find anywhere that explains how you actually return a value like this from a filter? Everything I can find seems to assume that the default outcome of any filter logic must be a redirect.

Thanks

EDIT: I've come to the conclusion that I am simply not using the filtering method in the way it was intended, and simply placing the handler in my controller method. But I would still like to know if it is possible to return data from a filter.

Answer (score -1):

In a controller:

```
if(Request::ajax()){

  return Response::json(['message' => 'Hi. Your request was ajax!', 'status' => 1]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I am indeed now employing the logic in my controller instead. This doesn't actually answer my original question though?

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution I found for that is to use `Session::flash` which populates data for the next request only and you can easily get the result anywhere. So for example :

> Route::filter('something', function() {
>
> if(false) {
>
> View:make('error); // or whenever you want
>
> } else {
>
> return Session:flash('result_var', $my_result_var);
>
> }
>
> });